# What are some good books (in English) about or by Nigamananda Paramhamsa?

Tags: translation-request, resource

Most of the stuff available online is in Bengali and Odiya. Is there any English book available to understand the teachings of Swami Nigamananda?

Comment: @Pratimaputra are you referring to Swami Nigamananda's Wikipedia entry?

Comment: @Pratimaputra they just have summary of his teachings not his works.

Comment: @Pratimaputra ohh really? I will check again then

Comment: @Pratimaputra so sorry but i cant find those links(maybe due to browser)plz answer this question if u find these links

Comment: @Pratimaputra thanks. Its a shame no translation is available of works of such a great saint.

Comment: @Pratimaputra true.I never even heard about Nigamananda before I came to this site. I read a lot about his assam bangiya saraswat mathas and such organisations.

Comment: @Pratimaputra thanks again for your kind help. Have u read swami's orignal works in Bengali?

Comment: @Pratimaputra thank u so much. I will email swamiji after some months.

Answer (score 3):

The complete information about books written by Swami Nigamananda Paramahansa is available at [Matha's website](http://www.absmath.org/books.php?page=Written%20Books).

[Books with English](http://nilachalsaraswatsangh.org/publication.html#eng) translation are also published by Nilachala Saraswata Sangha, a religious organization founded by Swami Nigamananda Paramahansa himself.

> [image]

In order to order the books you need to contact "Nilachal Sarswat Sangh" as ordering details given at [here](http://www.nilachalsaraswatsangh.org/index.php?option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=81).

Alternatively links to English Google books are provided on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigamananda_Paramahansa#Books):

> **English**
>
> - Swami Nigamānanda Paramahansa (1989). [Tantrika guru](https://books.google.com/books?id=WPooQwAACAAJ). Saraswata Sangha.
> - Swami Nigamānanda Paramahansa (1989). [Gyānī guru](https://books.google.com/books?id=-rBYQwAACAAJ). Nilachala Saraswata Sangha.
> - Swami Nigamānanda Paramahansa (1989). [Premika guru](https://books.google.com/books?id=akdCQwAACAAJ). Nilachala Saraswata Sangha.
> - Swami Nigamānanda Paramahansa (1963). [Yogī guru](https://books.google.com/books?id=yl9OQwAACAAJ). Nilachala Sarasvata Sangha.
> - Swami Nigamānanda Paramahansa (1969). [Brahamacharya Sadhana](https://books.google.com/books?id=i-IyQwAACAAJ&dq=inauthor:%22Nigam%C4%81nanda%20Sarasvati%20Deva%20%28Sv%C4%81m%C4%AB.%29%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=E2e-UYPeIMTorQeY2YGQDQ&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw). Nilachala Sarasvata Sangha.